# Change hint text of PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder in Android

Tags: android, google-places-api, hint

I am creating an Android Application. In that I am using `PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder` to get address from Google.

**I want to change the hint text** of search box in PlaceAutocomplete view.

I am using below code for opening the `PlaceAutocomplete` view.

```
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY).build(this);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: check this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlaceAutocompleteFragment#public-methods). In this link there is setHint() to change hint.

Comment: @SurenderKumar, Its indirectly calls the PlaceAutocomplete class

Comment: Please check out for the solution :
[How to change google places search hint text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366037/how-to-change-placeholder-text-in-an-autocomplete-activity-of-android-google-pla/47752403#47752403)

Answer (score 3):

For the new `Autocomplete.IntentBuilder`, you can override the hint string in your strings.xml file.

```
<string name="places_autocomplete_search_hint">SOME HINT TEXT</string>
```

I have not tested it on the old PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder, however.