# How to change placeholder text in an autocomplete activity of android google place?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using [Option 2: Use an intent to launch the autocomplete activity](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity)

Is it possible to change the "search" place holder text to something such as "enter your city". I found [a solution](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#placeholder_text) but for javascript, suppose support android as well.

It seems it could be done with [a PlaceAutocompleteFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398061/how-to-change-text-size-in-places-autocompletefragment-in-android), but I am using my own EditText to launch autocomplete by using an intent, so it is not helpful.

[image]

Comment: Are you using AutoCompleteTextView for this?

Comment: No, I am using normal EditText view, when users click on it, it will launch autocomplete activity. Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                            .setFilter(typeFilter)
                            .build(this);
            
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: You can use AutoCompleteTextView for that. You will also don't have to jump to another activity if you use this.

Comment: As mobile screen is small, I think using new activity will provide better UX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no way to change placeholder text with either auto complete activity or even with PlaceAutocompleteFragment because it also use autocomplete activity inside. The only way is using AutoCompleteTextView that you have full control on it. Google provides full sample code that is also easy to integrate and provide good UX.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceCompleteAdapter

I create a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64892097), hopefully it will be supported in the future.

Answer (score 10):

No there is no way and if you want than you have to create your own.
But as u use the EditText(mention in Comment Section) so may be this technique is useful for your.

Code:

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment;
autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);
    autocompleteFragment.setHint("Search New Location");
```

XMl :

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/left_drawable_padding"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_five"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_five"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_five"
android:background="@drawable/search_background"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />
```

and as i used `android:background="@drawable/search_background"` so u have to create your own background shape(acc. to your need).

first picture :
[image]

Second picture :
[image]

thrid picture :
[image]

Fourth picture :
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have time to check the answer that time, but I meant how to change the 'search' text in the second picture.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change the hint text with the autocomplete intent.
You need to make your own widget, like the PlaceAutocompleteFragment.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //places auto complete

    String apiKey = getString(R.string.api_key);

    /**
     * Initialize Places. For simplicity, the API key is hard-coded. In a production
     * environment we recommend using a secure mechanism to manage API keys.
     */
    if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey);
    }
```

// Create a new Places client instance.
PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

```
    // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
    AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));
    autocompleteFragment.setHint("Set Drop off");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :-

```
val autocompleteFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment)
                      as AutocompleteSupportFragment


autocompleteFragment.setHint("Search New Location")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for?

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) 
menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
searchView.setQueryHint("Your text");
```

Comment: what's the menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve google places functionality by two ways :
**1.) By using PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder**
**2.) By using PlaceAutocompleteFragment**

**CASE 1 :**

```
      private void openPlacesSearch()
{
private static final int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;

        try {
                            Intent intent =
                                    new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                                            .zzih("Enter pickup location") //set the hint text here
                                            .build(this);

                            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                        catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                            // TODO: Handle the error.
                        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                            // TODO: Handle the error.
                        }
}
```

**CASE 2:**
a.) Create a new Activity named "AddressSelectActivity.java"
b.) Don't forget to define that activity in manifest.xml

**Here is the code below :**

```
public class AddressSelectActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = AddressSelectActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;
    private PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_address_select);
        addAddressSuggestionListener();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE:

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());

                    LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();

                } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                    Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                    Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());

                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // The user canceled the operation.
                }

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void addAddressSuggestionListener()
    {
        autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
autocompleteFragment.setHint("Search Your Location...");

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are able to find build( ) method, search a method in that class which facilitate for the same.
Go to that class and search manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an auto complete text view, use setHint on the layout control, and the top-left title and hint text will both update.  If you just update the contained edit view, the top-left title will not change.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible, do it like this

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input);
    et.setHint("enter your city");
```

Comment: Not applicable for AutoCompleteSupportFragment.

Comment: That will do for the base input search field, but not the one that appears as popup